# Embedded Facebook Like button in Chrome extension renders then immediately disappears?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension, and it seems no matter where I put the provided code by facebook to get the "Like" and "Share" buttons to render, they immediately disappear less then a second after rendering. I have tried both importing the script facebook's provided way, and also copying and pasting the code that is generated by that script on a rendered page directly into the HTML source (so that it is no longer fetching the script, rather just rendering the `<iframe>` tag), and neither works.

Here is my CSS, and a snippet of the HTML

```
body {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#bg {
  height:100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height:100vh;
  min-width:100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.social {
  width:100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.body-background {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.nav-title {
  width:100%;
  background:white;
  opacity:0.6;
  max-height:69px;
  margin-top:10%;
  margin-bottom:auto;
}

.header-center {
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

.header-right {
  text-align:right;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

.title {
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  padding-bottom: 2.5px;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.time {
  max-width:310px;
}

.clock {
  width:100%;
}

.clock > h1 {
  font-size:120px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.shadow {
  color:white;
  text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #000,
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
    1px 1px 0 #000;
}

.date {
  font-size: 24px;
}

#hour {
  margin-right: -30px;
}

#minute {
  margin-left: -30px;
}

#next {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.6;

}

#left {
  text-align:left;
}

#right {
  text-align:right;
  float:right;
}
```

and the relevant HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="css/style.css">
  <meta name="twitter:widgets:csp" content="on">
  <title>New Tab | DJ Khaled's Inspiration</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/social-fb.js'></script>

  <div id="bg">
    <div class="content">
      <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='js/backgrounds.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='js/quotes.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='js/custom-background.js'></script>

      <div class="nav header-right">
         <div class="fb-like fb_iframe_widget" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/djkhaledtabs/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" fb-iframe-plugin-query="action=like&amp;app_id=&amp;container_width=1880&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdjkhaledtabs%2F&amp;layout=standard&amp;locale=en_US&amp;sdk=joey&amp;share=true&amp;show_faces=true">
                <span style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 450px; height: 25px;">
                  <iframe name="f15ee8ff68" width="1000px" height="1000px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" title="fb:like Facebook Social Plugin" src="https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/plugins/like.php?action=like&amp;app_id=&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df34123a408%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Ff35d731f4c%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;container_width=1880&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdjkhaledtabs%2F&amp;layout=standard&amp;locale=en_US&amp;sdk=joey&amp;share=true&amp;show_faces=true" style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 450px; height: 25px;" class="">
                  </iframe>
                </span>
              </div>
        <span>
          <img id="next" src="img/right-arrow.png" alt="Get More Inspiration">
        </span>
      </div>
    ....
</body>
</html>
```

It is also noteworthy that I'm using Twitter social media buttons that render without fail. I commented them out, in case they were not cooperating, and nothing changed unfortunately.

**UPDATE**

So in local development the button renders, disappears, and THEN reappears! I think it has something to do with adblock, but viewing the raw index.html file in any other browser yields the same error.

Comment: Could you please, give us a code sample?

Comment: apologies, the code has been added

Comment: Heads-up: screenshots of code tend to be poorly-received, since they're harder to read, and impossible to search/edit/test directly. Some folks might ding you with downvotes for that.

Comment: Seems weird. Can you check the console and see if anything is blocking at? And yea, might as well put in a form where in we can copy/edit :)

Comment: Updated with some actual code (y), also a few extra details.

Comment: I've added further details after experimenting locally and in other browsers @JeremyRajan

Comment: @james, I just ran it on fiddle. And it seems to work.. https://jsfiddle.net/Lgwsogsr/ . What you think? But, i did remove every js file attached tho.. It might be something to do with the script fb/social.js being loaded, as you are already using iframe.

Comment: I believe it has more to do with the chrome extension requirements. If I use the <div> provided by facebook to render the page then nothing shows up at all. By using the iframe that that turns into (and letting that call it's respective scripts) I at least see the button appear and disappear. I also tried loading just the button code into a blank html file and it exhibits the exact same behavior. @JeremyRajan